# parsing a variable from a scala twirl template to javascrpt in a seperate file

Tags: javascript, html, scala, playframework, twirl

Hi  i am currently trying to tidy some code up by moving some javascript into a seperate file however i am having a problem with parsing a variable into that the script needs this is the code i have tried so far:
The Script:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/percentageBarScript.js.percentage(total, incomplete)")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

code in JavaScript:

```
function percentage(total, incomplete) {

 var PercentT = Math.round((((total- incomplete) / total) * 100)).toString() + "%";
 var barProgress = document.getElementsByClassName("complete")[0].getElementsByClassName("bar")[0].style.width = PercentT;
 var barText = document.getElementsByClassName("complete")[0].getElementsByClassName("bar")[0].textContent = PercentT;

}
```